# Formatting HTML as text

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5

**UPDATE 2:**

In this section, I am trying to manually add in tabs and line spaces so the string is formatted when displayed via the pre tag.  But this does not work.

```
objStringBuilder.Append("<div>" & Environment.NewLine)
objStringBuilder.Append(vbTab & "<div>some text</div>" & Environment.NewLine)
objStringBuilder.Append("</div>" & Environment.NewLine)

Return "<pre>" & Server.HtmlEncode(objStringBuilder.ToString) & "</pre>"
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
return "<pre>" & Server.HtmlEncode("<div><div>some text</div></div>") & "</pre>"
```

I want it to display something like this

```
<div>
    <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

But it's diplaying like this, which is expected:

```
<div><div>some text</div></div>
```

I don't know how to get spaces, tabs, carriage returns into that string which are recognizable by the pre tag, as environment.newline and/or vbtab make no difference.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Is it possible to display HTML as text on your page in a formatted manner?  For example, it should contain white spaces, tabs etc etc for readability purposes:

From another question, I have learned how to display HTML as text as follows:

```
Server.HtmlEncode("<div>Some text</div>");
```

Comment: Why do you have double quotes followed by a set of single quotes too?

Comment: Not sure, I think those got inserted automatically when I clicked the code button here at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a very useful to parse HTML documents, [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) class provides an ability to format XML documents. So why don't use both of them for HTML formatting? Sorry, I'm not familiar with `VB`, so my example in `C#`:

First, creating a new document:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
htmlDoc.LoadHtml("<div><div>some text</div></div>");
```

[`XElement.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse.aspx) method doesn't like when then e.g. just text is not wrapped in tags, so I'm adding a root `div` tag in that case:

```
if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode.HasChildNodes)
{
    bool wrapperNeeded = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes
        .Cast<HtmlNode>()
        .Any(n => n.NodeType != HtmlNodeType.Element);

    if (wrapperNeeded)
    {
        var wrapper = htmlDoc.CreateElement("div");
        wrapper.AppendChildren(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes);
        htmlDoc.DocumentNode.RemoveAllChildren();
        htmlDoc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(wrapper);
    }
}
```

then I'm saving the document as a string:

```
string html = null;
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    htmlDoc.Save(writer);
    html = writer.ToString();
}
```

and finally, creating a new element and converting it to a string (with formatting):

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(html);
html = element.ToString();
```

`html` now contains a value `<div>\r\n  <div>some text</div>\r\n</div>`, and if you html encode it wrap this into e.g. `<pre>` tag wou'll get the desired output:

```
<div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

A note: I didn't test it carefully, I just want to show that it could be done this way.

Answer (score 3):

One of these might also be useful for readability.

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

http://webcodingstudio.com/blog/jquery-syntax-highlight-plugin

http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/16-free-javascript-code-syntax-highlighters-for-better-programming/

Comment: Is it not possible without having to download plugins, I just want to add some spaces and carriage returns to the html.

Comment: Adding <pre> tags around your content will preserve the existing line breaks. So if you want the line breaks then add them into the source wherever you want but there is no magic .net framework method that can format HTML in your own particular favourite style. You need to do some googling for a code beautifier library that you can use.

Comment: I understand that, what I don't understand is why something like environment.newline or vbtab do not work.

Comment: I don't know, maybe you should post the code sample that you're using to insert the environment newline or tabs and someone might have a chance at answering that question. I don't understand why you'd want to write your own parser to insert these characters when you can utilise a free library thats already written and tested.

Answer (score 1):

VB.Net has a cool thing called XML literals that let you write XML without requiring string syntax. As long as you follow XML syntax (pretty much close all tags) you can use this to write HTML chunks:

```
Dim S = <div>
            <div>some text</div>
        </div>
```

When you called `ToString` on that there's an option to preserve formatting:

```
S.ToString(SaveOptions.None)
```

This outputs:

```
<div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the encoded HTML fragment inside a `pre` or `tt` tag.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but you are really funny. You are NOT supplying any spaces or tabs to HtmlEncode. So why do you think, they will exist afterwards? They don't materialize out of thin air... Obviously, what you really want to do is to first beautify that HTML and only than encode it.

Comment: Exactly, I don't know how to add the spaces, carriage returns, tabs etc etc into the string.  I tried environment.newline and vbtab, but they made no difference.

Comment: strange. I can't test it right now, so I can't provide any more hints, sorry.